# Entity Framework "A command is already in progress" error

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

```
var fd = dbContext.FanduelPositions;
var dk = dbContext.DraftkingsPositions;
var baseTable = (from d in (IEnumerable<IPosition>)dk select d).Concat(from f in (IEnumerable<IPosition>)fd select f);
            
var positions = (from x in baseTable
    join y in baseTable
    on new { x.EventKey, x.CustomParticipant, x.BetCategory, x.CustomLine } equals new { y.EventKey, y.CustomParticipant, y.BetCategory, y.CustomLine }
    select new
    {
        fdPos = x.PositionId,
        fdOdds = x.OddsDecimal,
        fdbetPos = x.BetPosition,
        dkPos = y.PositionId,
        dkOdds = y.OddsDecimal,
        dkbetPos = y.BetPosition,
    }).Where(c => c.fdbetPos != c.dkbetPos).Where(p => (1 / p.fdOdds) + (1 / p.dkOdds) < .985);
return Ok(positions.ToList());
```

I have the above LINQ in a .net core API controller. I am getting the following error-

```
 An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'PROJECT_NAME.DataContext'.
      Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException (0x80004005): A command is already in progress:
```

I have my dbcontext being created with a `ServiceLifetime` of `Transient`.  I am wondering how I can avoid this error.  I was hoping a single SQL statement would be created that would make this DB request however it looks like that is not the case.  Performance is a huge factor for me, the raw sql takes 150ms and I am looking for a similar timeframe from the LINQ so I would like it submitted in a single query if at all possible.  Not sure how to fix this block of code to avoid `A command is already in progress:`

Comment: My guess is that the casts to `IEnumerable<IPosition>` are causing client-side evaluation, so doing a self-join on `baseTable` is causing it to attempt to perform that query (for `y`) while performing that query (for `x`). I'm posting this as a comment for someone else to run with if they can test and confirm that.

Comment: @madreflection Do you know if there is another way I could structure my `Concat` without using an interface? Basically my 2 tables each has a subset of 7 columns that are the same across those tables, so I am trying to take those 7 columns and create a union all between them while ignoring the other columns.  To do that, I created this interface but if there is another approach..

Comment: Probably change both `select d` and `select f` to `select new { ... }` with the same properties in each so that you're projecting queryable sequences of concrete types. That is to say that your `IPosition` interface isn't helpful for the purposes of generating a query against the database. EF needs concrete types.

Comment: I think problem that you have added Cast `IEnumerable<IPosition>`. Project to some common class. Otherwise you load two tables into the memory. Not sure why it cause exception, but looks like LINQ to objects keeps not closed Enumerator.

Comment: I would propose that your data model needs some normalization. If you have two tables that share common properites, they could be a single table with a discriminator column, and 1-to-optional-1 child tables for the properties specific to each, if any. That would eliminate the need for `Concat` (`UNION ALL`) and greatly simplify the query.

Comment: For complex loose relationships like this, you're probably best off creating a View in Postgres for the concatenated results of the two tables, or potentially the entire query across all 3 tables would be more suitable. the error is likely due to the casting of the IEnumerable within the first query in that to execute the second joining query the DbContext would be expected to execute to resolve the first.